# Apply function across multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

Please find here a very small subset of a long data.table I am working with

```
dput(dt)
structure(list(id = 1:15, pnum = c(4298390L, 4298390L, 4298390L, 
    4298558L, 4298558L, 4298559L, 4298559L, 4299026L, 4299026L, 4299026L, 
    4299026L, 4300436L, 4300436L, 4303566L, 4303566L), invid = c(15L, 
    101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 103L, 104L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 87L, 
    111L, 2L, 60L), fid = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CORN", "DowCor", 
    "KIM", "Texas"), class = "factor"), dom_kn = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), prim_kn = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), pat_kn = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), net_kn = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), age_kn = c(1L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), legclaims = c(5L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 2L), n_inv = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("id", 
    "pnum", "invid", "fid", "dom_kn", "prim_kn", "pat_kn", "net_kn", 
    "age_kn", "legclaims", "n_inv"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -15L))
```

I am looking to apply a tweaked *greater than comparison* in 5 different columns.

Within each `pnum` (patent), there are multiple `invid` (inventors). I want to compare the values of the columns `dom_kn`, `prim_kn`, `pat_kn`, `net_kn`, and `age_kn` per row, to the values in the other rows with the same `pnum`. The comparison is simply `>` and if the value is indeed bigger than the other, one "point" should be attributed.

So for the first row `pnum == 4298390` and `invid == 15`, you can see the values in the five columns are all `1`, while the values for `invid == 101 | 102` are all zero. This means that if we individually compare (is greater than?) each value in the first row to each cell in the second and third row, the total sum would be 10 points. In every single comparison, the value in the first row is bigger and there are 10 comparisons. 
The number of comparisons is by design `5 * (n_inv -1)`. 
The result I am looking for for row 1 should then be `10 / 10 = 1`.

For `pnum == 4298558` the columns `net_kn` and `age_kn` both have values 1 in the two rows (for `invid` 103 and 104), so that each should get 0.5 points (if there would be three inventors with value 1, everyone should get 0.33 points). The same goes for `pnum == 4298558`.

For the next `pnum == 4299026` all values are zero so every comparison should result in 0 points.

Thus note the difference: There are three different dyadic comparisons

```
1 > 0 --> assign 1
1 = 1 --> assign 1 / number of positive values in column subset
0 = 0 --> assign 0
```

**Desired result**
An extra column `result` in the data.table with values `1 0 0 0.2 0.8 0.2 0.8 0 0 0 0 1 0 0.8 0.2`

Any suggestions on how to compute this efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Something is not clear to me, for `pnum==4298558`, net_kn and age_kn have both 1, so no one is greater than the other and they should get 0, according to your description. Why is not the case?

Comment: Description might have been unclear. They both have value 1 and need to be compared to next row which also have value 1. If they are equal and 1, they should get value of 1 / number of positive values in the column in the patent

Comment: "The comparison is simply > and if the value is indeed bigger than the other, one "point" should be attributed". They are equal and so they get 0, why are they getting 1?

Comment: Ok I need to reframe that. If in the same column and the same patent multiple values have value 1, the assigned value is not zero. It needs to be the 1 divided by the number of non-zero values

Comment: Those columns will only ever take the value 1 or 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vars = grep('_kn', names(dt), value = T)

# all you need to do is simply assign the correct weight and sum the numbers up
dt[, res := 0]
for (var in vars)
  dt[, res := res + get(var) / .N, by = c('pnum', var)]

# normalize
dt[, res := res/sum(res), by = pnum]
#    id    pnum invid    fid dom_kn prim_kn pat_kn net_kn age_kn legclaims n_inv res
# 1:  1 4298390    15   CORN      1       1      1      1      1         5     3 1.0
# 2:  2 4298390   101   CORN      0       0      0      0      0         0     3 0.0
# 3:  3 4298390   102   CORN      0       0      0      0      0         0     3 0.0
# 4:  4 4298558   103 DowCor      0       0      0      1      1         2     2 0.2
# 5:  5 4298558   104 DowCor      1       1      1      1      1         5     2 0.8
# 6:  6 4298559   103 DowCor      0       0      0      1      1         2     2 0.2
# 7:  7 4298559   104 DowCor      1       1      1      1      1         5     2 0.8
# 8:  8 4299026   106  Texas      0       0      0      0      0         0     4 NaN
# 9:  9 4299026   107  Texas      0       0      0      0      0         0     4 NaN
#10: 10 4299026   108  Texas      0       0      0      0      0         0     4 NaN
#11: 11 4299026   109  Texas      0       0      0      0      0         0     4 NaN
#12: 12 4300436    87    KIM      1       1      1      1      1         5     2 1.0
#13: 13 4300436   111    KIM      0       0      0      0      0         0     2 0.0
#14: 14 4303566     2 DowCor      1       1      1      1      1         5     2 0.8
#15: 15 4303566    60 DowCor      1       0      0      1      0         2     2 0.2
```

Dealing with the above `NaN` case (arguably the correct answer), is left to the reader.

Comment: Truly an awesome solution. I did not even know you could add column names to the `by` parameter in a `data.table`. That's very neat. Also quite brilliant you managed to ignore the difficult explanation and realize that you could achieve the same by summing across rows within a column. It took me until halfway through Batman v Superman to realize that!

Comment: For my understanding, is it correct the `.N` here equals the columnsum of the specific variable, rather than the count of the number of rows? If so, is this because you are adding the `'var` in the `by` statement? Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. `.N` is the number of rows for each unique combination of "pnum" and given "var".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fastish solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
 group_by(pnum) %>% # group by pnum
 mutate_each(funs(. == max(.) & max(.) != 0), ends_with('kn')) %>%
 #give a 1 if the value is the max, and not 0. Only for the column with kn
 mutate_each(funs(. / sum(.)) , ends_with('kn')) %>%
 #correct for multiple maximums
 select(ends_with('kn')) %>%
 #remove all non kn columns
 do(data.frame(x = rowSums(.[-1]), y = sum(.[-1]))) %>%
 #make a new data frame with x = rowsums for each indvidual
 # and y the colusums
 mutate(out = x/y)
 #divide by y (we could just use /5 if we always have five columns)
```

giving your desired output in the column `out`:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 4]
Groups: pnum [6]

      pnum     x     y   out
     (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1  4298390     5     5   1.0
2  4298390     0     5   0.0
3  4298390     0     5   0.0
4  4298558     1     5   0.2
5  4298558     4     5   0.8
6  4298559     1     5   0.2
7  4298559     4     5   0.8
8  4299026   NaN   NaN   NaN
9  4299026   NaN   NaN   NaN
10 4299026   NaN   NaN   NaN
11 4299026   NaN   NaN   NaN
12 4300436     5     5   1.0
13 4300436     0     5   0.0
14 4303566     4     5   0.8
15 4303566     1     5   0.2
```

The NaNs come from the groups with no winners, convert them back using eg:

```
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```